# Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow error on item update

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to create a simple workflow which will update a field in my current splistitem.
It keeps giving me the following error. Any idea on this ??

The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.

by the way i tried all kind of fields like title => string
datetime => date.

infact error is not related to my information type.
Can it be related with user rights ? I also tried checking out and updating item then checking in in wf too.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what i want to do is archieve an item by copying it from a doc. library to another.

Answer (score 3):

Does your destination document library have any "required" fields/columns that perhaps aren't being populated by the workflow?

Comment: no it doesn't. but my file is created by workflow step : copy item...
btw i solved my problem with create item in list,instead of using copy from list to list.